# Placing the <TextInput /> Tag Under a <ScrollView />

Tags: react-native, scrollview

A few days ago, while working on a chatting app, I came across an issue which I wasn't able to solve. I had to keep an Text Input  under a Scroll View, but it wouldn't appear there, here is the code :

```
       <MyStatusbar />
            <MyHeader title = 'Jane Doe' color = '#6a11cb'/>

            <ImageBackground style = {  styles.IMG } source = { images.gradient_1 }>

              <ScrollView>

                <Text style = { styles.disclaimer }>Content is Encrypet as per a private database. Oval Inc Corp will not be held responsile for any leaks within Images.</Text>
    
                {
                  this.state.MessageArray.map((message) => {
                    return(
                      <View key = { message }>
                          <TouchableOpacity 
                           onPress = {() => { 

                          }}
                          >
                              <Text style = { isNaN(message) ? styles.goingMessages : styles.incomingMessages } >{ isNaN(message) ? message : this.state.MessageArray2[message] }</Text>
                          </TouchableOpacity>

                      </View>
                    );
                  })
                }

              </ScrollView>

              <View>
                <TextInput style = { styles.orInput1 } placeholder = 'Type Here...' />
              </View>

            </ImageBackground>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did it appear before?

Comment: You should set `flex: 1` in contentContainerStyle

Comment: Yes it appeared when I put the Input before the ScrollView and thanks for the flex : 1!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
<ImageBackground 
  style={{flex: 1, width: "100%", height: "100%",}} 
  source={images.gradient_1}>
  
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView>... ...</ScrollView>
  </View>

  <View>
    <TextInput style={styles.orInput1} placeholder="Type Here..." />
  </View>
</ImageBackground>;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code gave me an idea. When it didn't work, I tried it everywhere, turns out it works when you apply it to the view where the Text Input exists.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you wrote Text instead of TextInput is that the error? If so it is just a syntax error that broke your app